# InputAccessoryView above UITabBar

Tags: ios

I'm currently trying to place a custom `inputAccessoryView` above `UITabBar`. But as you see below, the actual `inputAccessoryView` covers the `UITabBar`. Is there a way to do so ? Maybe by putting some bottom constraint on the superview of the `inputAccessoryView` ?

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}


- (UIView *)inputAccessoryView {
    self.inputAccView.delegate = self;
    return self.inputAccView;
}
```

[image]